# Postgres - conditionally setting a variable to null

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, postgresql-9.1

I am currently using postgres 9.1 and I am trying to update a table to set incorrect values to null. In particular I wish to set all observations where the the number of months between the two observations is not equal to 8 to NULL as my prior calculation for 'variable' will be invalid.

I have tried to write a conditional update but have had no success. I am dealing with a large number of observations (3.5m +) and will have to loop this procedure many times so if it's possible to restrict the amount of updating that would be fantastic. Thanks!

```
UPDATE table
SET variable = CASE WHEN
(
SELECT
(date_part('year',age(datadate,(lag(datadate, 8) OVER W))) * 12) + date_part('month',age(date_trunc('month',datadate),(lag(date_trunc('month',datadate), 8) OVER W))) 
FROM table
WINDOW W AS (PARTITION BY permno ORDER BY datadate)
) != '8'
THEN NULL 
 ELSE variable END;
```

Comment: Show sample data and desired result

Answer (score -1):

1. In your query, you are updating all the records in the table which can be narrowed down to only needed rows using where clause and having the predicate condition.
2. You can use limit and row_number() to restrict the number of rows updated in each statement execution.

Please refer : http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-window.html for other pagination options.

If your table is partitioned already, then you can update each child table separately using 'only' keyword.